# Counting multiple values in one column

Tags: mysql, if-statement, sum, conditional-statements

long time reader, first time poster. I have 1 table from which I need to gather the count the amount of time some value (found in column 'product_group') is repeated and also have to sometime take into account value from a a different column ('product_type').

I've searched on the forums for long hours and this is what I came up with for the moment... My problem is that I have a feeling that this is not the most efficient way of doing it. Also, it doesn't let me count if there is none of the conditioned matched (e.g. else condition).

```
SELECT
   SUM(IF(record_type NOT LIKE '%TypeA%' AND product_group LIKE '%Product1%', 1, 0)) AS Value1,
   SUM(IF(record_type NOT LIKE '%TypeA%' AND product_group LIKE '%Product2%', 1, 0)) AS Value2,
   SUM(IF(record_type NOT LIKE '%TypeA%' AND product_group LIKE '%Product3%', 1, 0)) AS Value3,
   SUM(IF(record_type NOT LIKE '%TypeA%' AND product_group LIKE '%Product4%', 1, 0)) AS Value4,
   SUM(IF(record_type NOT LIKE '%TypeA%' AND product_group LIKE '%Product5%', 1, 0)) AS Value5,
   SUM(IF(record_type NOT LIKE '%TypeA%' AND product_group LIKE '%Product6%', 1, 0)) AS Value6,
   SUM(IF(record_type NOT LIKE '%TypeA%' AND product_group LIKE '%Product7%', 1, 0)) AS Value7,
   SUM(IF(record_type NOT LIKE '%TypeA%' AND product_group LIKE '%Product8%', 1, 0)) AS Value8,
   SUM(product_group NOT LIKE '%Product9%') AS Value9,  
   SUM(IF(record_type LIKE '%TypeA%', 1, 0)) AS Value10
FROM
   [tables]
WHERE
   [conditions]
```

My objective with that is to find out weighted user productivity. So I calculate each time a user handles a specific product. Depending on the type of product, I will modify the value (from 0.83 to 1.25 of original) to take into account the complexity. Once all the different products weight have been "crunched", I add them all and then divide by the amount of hours worked.

The math is done outside of the SQL query in my PHP code. I was wondering if it might be better to run multiple sequential SQL queries with the conditions in the WHERE section instead of my previous method. Here's what it would look like in such a case...

```
SELECT 
   COUNT(*)*0.95 as `Value1`
FROM
   [tables]
WHERE
   record_type NOT LIKE '%TypeA%'
   AND  product_group LIKE '%Product1%'
   [other conditions]
```

And then repeat for all the other 10 or so values...

So that pretty much sums it up. Any suggestions, hints, links, you can share with me will be greatly appreciated as I've pretty much exhausted all resources I could think of.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method is the better method.  Running separate SQL queries would end up scanning the table multiple times.  Much better to just go through the table once.

You can also probably do the extra arithmetic in SQL.  But if you already have it written in the application code, no need to change that.